# Necessary and sufficient condition for Lyapunov stability

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, lyapunov-functions

Suppose $J $ is a real square matrix and matrix $V = V^\textsf{T}$ is positive-definite. Define $ A = V J $.

Can we show that $J ^\textsf{T} + J$ is negative-definite if, and only if, $A^\textsf{T} P +  P A $ is negative-definite for some positive-definite matrix $P = P^\textsf{T}$?

The "if" part is easy. Assume $J ^\textsf{T} + J$ is negative-definite. Let $P = V^{-1}$. Then  $A^\textsf{T} P +  P A  =  (VJ)^\textsf{T} V^{-1} +  V^{-1} (VJ) = J ^\textsf{T} + J $ is negative-definite.

What about the "only if" part?

Thanks !

Comment: The answer is clearly negative. Had $A^TP+PA\prec0$ implied that $A^TV^{-1}+V^{-1}A\prec0$ for all $V\succ0$, then in particular, when $V=I$, we would obtain “$\,$stability $\implies$ ‘non-symmetric negative definite’$\,$”, which we know is false.

Comment: thanks. Could one show alternatively that if $J^\textsf{T} B +  B J < 0$ for all positive definite matrices $B$, then $J^\textsf{T}  + J  < 0$ ?

Comment: Yes. Just take $B=I$.

Comment: lol, yes obvious. sorry for bother but many thanks!